# Basic Crowdsale Contract

Tags: solidity, remix, crowdsale, openzeppelin-contracts

I am learning to develop smart contract using Solidity. Currently, I am working and test the feature of following crowdsale contract.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.8.0/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol

This contract constructor has three different values.

1. rate
2. wallet address
3. token address

I am confused about the first one that is "rate". what value should i have to pass here ?

for example, I want to sell 1 token at cost of 1 ether then what should i pass here ?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see the function

```
function _getTokenAmount(uint256 _weiAmount) internal view returns (uint256) {
    return _weiAmount.mul(rate);
  }
```

It states that for 1 wei, the no of tokens will be **1*rate**.

> for example, I want to sell 1 token at cost of 1 ether then what
>   should i pass here ?

This depends on number of decimals in your toke  contract. For eg, if you have 18 decimals,then

**token = wei * rate**

```
1 Token = 1 ether * rate

10 ^18 token = 10 ^18 wei * rate

=> rate = 1
```

Comment: I have deployed the crowdsale contract with my fixed supply token but it gives an exection.

Comment: my fixed supply has 18 decimal

Comment: exception is constructor should be payable if you send the value

Comment: You need to make any function that accepts ether payable

Comment: you can see in my crowdsale contract there is a function name buyTokens() that is payable.

Comment: i also notice that whenever i commented the function call of transfer() from crowdsale contract, it works. I think there is some issue at that time of sending token to beneficiary.

Answer (score 0):

http://eth-converter.com/

Wei to Ether

Wei is the 18 digits that go into an Ether

Answer (score 0):

Rate is explained in the OpenZeppelin Contracts Crowdsale documentation: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/crowdsales#crowdsale-rate

You can also ask questions about how to use OpenZeppelin Contracts in the [Community Forum](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/)

Disclosure: I am the the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin